Printf() 45 arguments in CUDA
Parallel printing makes it very difficult to trace variables because of the order in which threads fire.
For this reason, I print many variables in one line for testing.
I'm trying to print 45 indices from a bool array in printf like so:
printf( "[%hu%hu%hu%hu%hu][%hu%hu%hu%hu%hu][%hu%hu%hu%hu%hu]\n"
        "[%hu%hu%hu%hu%hu][%hu%hu%hu%hu%hu][%hu%hu%hu%hu%hu]\n"
        "[%hu%hu%hu%hu%hu][%hu%hu%hu%hu%hu][%hu%hu%hu%hu%hu]\n\n",
u[0],
u[1],
u[2],
u[3],
u[4],
u[5],
u[6],
u[7],
u[8],
u[9],
u[10],
u[11],
u[12],
u[13],
u[14],
u[15],
u[16],
u[17],
u[18],
u[19]
u[20],
u[21],
u[22],
u[23],
u[24],
u[25],
u[26],
u[27],
u[28],
u[29],
u[30],
u[31],
u[32],
u[33],
u[34],
u[35],
u[36],
u[37],
u[38],
u[39],
u[40],
u[41],
u[42],
u[43],
u[44],
u[45]);

This is obviously running inside a kernel, and it works, but the output comes out like this:
[11111][11111][11111]
[11111][11111][11111]
[1195633005623389][266612392595893005626661][95899589300563005626661]

[11111][11111][11111]
[11111][11111][11111]
[1195633005623389][266612392595893005626661][95899589300563005626661]

[11111][11111][11111]
[11111][11111][11111]
[1195633005623389][266612392595893005626661][95899589300563005626661]

[11111][11111][11111]
[11111][11111][11111]
[1195633005623389][266612392595893005626661][95899589300563005626661]

[11111][11111][11111]
[11111][11111][11111]
[1195633005623389][266612392595893005626661][95899589300563005626661]

[11111][11111][11111]
[11111][11111][11111]
[1195633005623389][266612392595893005626661][95899589300563005626661]

[11111][11111][11111]
[11111][11111][11111]
[1195633005623389][266612392595893005626661][95899589300563005626661]

[11111][11111][11111]
[11111][11111][11111]
[1195633005623389][266612392595893005626661][95899589300563005626661]

[11111][11111][11111]
[11111][11111][11111]
[1195633005623389][266612392595893005626661][95899589300563005626661]

With each thread output here separated by the double line.
What I've tried so far:

the printf works perfectly fine outside of the kernel
I've changed the order of the indices, and only the last 15 args come out like garbage
I've tried increasing the printf buffer size and also using shorts %hu

    size_t sz = 1048576 * 10000;
    cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitPrintfFifoSize, sz);

No clue why I'm getting garbage values at the end -- my best guess is the stack itself has run out of memory?
Does anyone know how I can printf 45 arguments inside a cuda kernel?
NOTE: I'm only using the plain C variety, compiling with nvcc and Visual Studio's cl.exe directly

I have never touched cuda, but a little bit of google says that there is such notion as global function, and that it uses shared memory for argument passing, and the limit for one argument list is 256 bytes.

"The printf() command can accept at most 32 arguments in addition to the format string. Additional arguments beyond this will be ignored, and the format specifier output as-is."

@paleonix I literally just found it right after you lol

man that sucks :(

@bigcodeszzer "man that sucks :(" Maybe it isn't the specification that sucks. What is wrong with using loops? printf is a massive bottleneck either way, so if you are using it you already threw all concerns about performance out the window.

@Lundin because of the print order, I just end up having to track one thread line per each paragraph of print out put for pages and pages. Eventually I may be running over 200 threads and it's impossible to track one thread ouput

That has absolutely nothing to do with how the printing algorithm is executed.

I included the context at the top of the question.

POSIX provides flockfile()
and funlockfile() and ftrylockfile() (all defined on the same page).  Are they usable with CUDA?  If so, you can lock the file stream, write multiple printing operations, (flush the output) and then unlock the file — and other printing will not be interleaved.

@JonathanLeffler that's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for. I pipe to txt file output and could easily "sort" the thread/lines manually but that would surely take significant time per run and be horrible for debugging. I'll have to look around for that.

@JonathanLeffler I'm pretty certain that that these are not available in CUDA device code. Neither is fprintf. One can create a critical section using e.g a cuda::binary_semaphore instead.

@paleonix not sure what those are but its core cuda c++ and I'm only using plain C. What I think I will do is just lock the entire kernel and have it run one thread at a time and minimize my data size which should be sufficient for debugging.

CUDA (nowadays) is a C++ dialect, there is no CUDA C, so restricting yourself to the C-like subset of CUDA  is somewhat artificial. Either way binary_semaphore  is just doing atomic CASs and memory fences which are available in that C subset, just more error-prone to use. Other newer features like memcpy_async from global to shared memory actually require using C++ interfaces (or inline PTX).

As others have mentioned, there is a limit of 32 arguments for a cuda device printf.
AFAICT, the only reason you're doing a printf with so many args is that you want to have one line for a given thread printf. And be able to separate the output from various threads.
There is a workaround of sorts ...
For debug printing in a multiprocessing environment, [I've found] it helps to associate a message with a timestamp and a thread identifier. And, optionally, a function name and line number.
Caveat: I'm only slightly familiar with cuda in general, but I've done similar debug in the past ...
For cuda devices, clock64 returns the timestamp counter value. And, threadIdx.x is a thread identifier of sorts.
AFAICT, because cuda doesn't have vprintf, we should use a macro. Loosely:
Edit: Adjusted per paleonix
#if MY_CUDA_DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt,_av...) \
    printf("[%llu/%u.%u] " _fmt, \
        clock64(),blockIdx.x,threadIdx.x,_av)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt,_av...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

dbgprt("hello %s\n","world");

The preprocessor output is:
printf("[%llu/%u.%u] " "hello %s\n", clock64(),blockIdx.x,threadIdx.x,"world");

We divert all printf output into a file. Then, after a run, on the host we can use a post-processing script to separate the various messages into per-thread logfiles by parsing the per-line prefix information.
Of course, this is only a simple example. Adjust what appears in the [] part of the message as needed.

Minor addition: threadIdx on it's own is not unique in CUDA, you need blockIdx as well.

@paleonix Thanks for that. I guessed that might be the case, but was too timid to add it [I saw some page that just used if (threadIdx.x == 0) printf(...);].

Depends on the context, but probably the goal there was to print one line per block.

@paleonix The key point is that we get some sort of atomic state on a given line [quickly]. What I've done in the past for my stuff is to have the post processing script do the heavy lifting of splitting/combining information from the various threads/blocks as desired. In fact, my scripts would produce various different reports, based on how I needed to compare things.

I've just been piping my output at the command line directly into a text file. It would be easy to tag the prints by thread and by line number. But my outputs will eventually be so large that having to read the file and sort it out would take a long time per run. Even building an sql database from the output file would probably be pretty slow.

@bigcodeszzer A lot of this is derived from debug stuff I've developed over time. I use a perl script to do the post-mortel splitting/joining. It's pretty fast but still can take a few minutes to process a multi-gigabyte file. With a C post processing program, it could be made faster. And, you could modify/hack up the program to do filtering on the fly, based on some command line option. My script started simply. I added features as I needed them to debug specific problems I had with the original program being debugged.

Think I figured it out myself -- and there is no solution?
According to the CUDA programming guide

7.35.2. Limitations
Final formatting of the printf()output takes place on the host system. This means that the format string must be understood by the host-system’s compiler and C library. Every effort has been made to ensure that the format specifiers supported by CUDA’s printf function form a universal subset from the most common host compilers, but exact behavior will be host-OS-dependent.
As described in Format Specifiers, printf() will accept all combinations of valid flags and types. This is because it cannot determine what will and will not be valid on the host system where the final output is formatted. The effect of this is that output may be undefined if the program emits a format string which contains invalid combinations.
The printf() command can accept at most 32 arguments in addition to the format string. Additional arguments beyond this will be ignored, and the format specifier output as-is.

